Confused about the cofinality of a cardinal
The definition of cofinality I am most used to is this:
The cofinality of a cardinal is the least ordinal that is the order type of a cofinal sequence reaching that cardinal.
Intuitively from this definition I get why $\newcommand{\cof}{\mathrm{cof}}\cof(\aleph_0) = \aleph_0$.
I get to $\cof(\aleph_\omega)$ which is $\omega$ because an $\omega$-indexed sequence is needed to "reach the cardinal".
But then I get to $\aleph_3$ and I don't understand why its cofinality is itself and not $3$ if we can reach it in three steps starting from $\aleph_0$.
Obviously I am not going to break set theory so there is some misunderstanding I am having here so please clarify the fault in my thinking.

Please use MathJax to format all mathematical symbols in your posts here. I'll edit your question for you this time.

The cofinality of an infinite cardinal cannot possibly be finite. Try to write things down formally and you'll see that your proposed sequence isn't cofinal.

There are an awful lot of ordinals between $\aleph_2$ and $\aleph_3$...

It's easier to think of the cofinality of an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ as the smallest cardinal number of strictly smaller cardinals which sum to $\kappa$. So the cofinality of $\aleph_0$ is $\aleph_0$ because any finite sum of finite cardinals is finite, while the sum of $\aleph_0$-many $1$'s equals $\aleph_0$. Similarly the sum of strictly less than $\aleph_3$-many cardinals strictly less than $\aleph_3$ will be strictly less than $\aleph_3$.

You say we can reach $\aleph_3$ in three steps. What are these three steps?
Not $\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2$. This sequence doesn't "reach" $\aleph_3$, since $\sup\{\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2\} = \aleph_2$.
Not $\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\aleph_3$. The cofinality of $\kappa$ is defined in terms of sequences of ordinals strictly less than $\kappa$. If we were allowed to include $\kappa$ in the sequence, every cardinal would have cofinality $1$, since $\sup\{\kappa\} = \kappa$.
So you see that to "reach" $\aleph_3$, you'll have to start naming ordinals $\alpha$ that live in the interval $\aleph_2<\alpha<\aleph_3$. How many of these do you need to get all the way up to $\aleph_3$? The answer is $\aleph_3$, though this is not immediately obvious. The proof will immediately generalize to prove the theorem that every successor cardinal $\kappa$ is regular, meaning that $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa) = \kappa$.
